# Find all of the street segments within a 30 meter square surrounding each of 1000 points. Do it as fast as possible

Tags: postgresql

I have a fast solution using PostgreSQL.  I also have a 8.75 times faster solution using a custom database plus a custom index.

The custom solution is working: implementing it for all of North America is the next step. However, I want to be sure that I have not over-looked a PostgreSQL solution that is just as fast (or faster).

The solution must return all of the street segments that are within a 30 meter square surrounding each point. But, if for the sake of speed, it also returns some street segments that are within a somewhat larger square, say 37.5 meter square, that is acceptable.  (My custom solution does this as a result of the tessilated tiling it employs).

The best Postgres solution I have come up with creates a single query that returns all 1000 solutions.  It looks like the below, but with all 1000 points covered. (Each ST_MakeEnvelope creates the 30 meter square surrounding each of the points).

```
SELECT 0 AS position, segment_id 
FROM roads  
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(-87.584051340952,50.9904613494613,-87.583193442952,50.9910013500013, 4326), geom_way)  

UNION ALL  SELECT 1 AS position, segment_id 
FROM roads  
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(-87.632028114596,50.9314626994627,-87.631171305396,50.9320027000027, 4326), geom_way)  

UNION ALL  SELECT 2 AS position, segment_id 
FROM roads  
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(-87.684002999977,50.8724640494641,-87.683147275777,50.873004050004, 4326), geom_way)  

UNION ALL  
SELECT 3 AS position, segment_id 
FROM roads  
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(-87.91989093966,50.8134653994654,-87.91903629686,50.8140054000054, 4326), geom_way)  

UNION ALL  
SELECT 4 AS position, segment_id 
FROM roads  
WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(-87.616034053248,50.7544667494668,-87.615180488048,50.7550067500068, 4326), geom_way)
```

I create the query programmatically, and pass it to Postgres using ODBC.

On my computer, this query is returning the results for 1,022 positions in one second. On the same computer, the custom database plus custom index is returning the results for 8,940 positions in one second.

Please show me how to write (a potentially sophisticated) Postgres query that is just as fast or faster!

Comment: If you query for only one city, are you sure the planner uses your indexed geom_way? I have not tested it but [e.g](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253974/why-is-st-intersects-faster-than/253987) for older postgis, you'd need special syntax so that your index is used

Comment: I have verified that the index for the geom_way column is being used.

Comment: The explain panel in pgAdmin shows that the && operator is used first in order to find all of the segments that contain the point within their bounding box.  The results are then filtered by the _st_intersects function, which chooses just those segments which actually intersect the envelope I provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short, you can factor all your envelops in a CTE then let the engine query them against roads

```
WITH cte (pos, geom) AS (select * from (values (0, ST_MakeEnvelope(64666.5,64666.5,64667.5,64667.5, 4326))
,(1, ST_MakeEnvelope(87392.5,87392.5,87393.5,87393.5, 4326))
,(2, ST_MakeEnvelope(69426.5,69426.5,69427.5,69427.5, 4326))
,(3, ST_MakeEnvelope(71599.5,71599.5,71600.5,71600.5, 4326))
,(4, ST_MakeEnvelope(45573.5,45573.5,45574.5,45574.5, 4326))
  ) as foo) SELECT pos,roads.* FROM roads,cte WHERE ST_Intersects(loc, cte.geom);
```

On my machine 6000 results in 250ms

---

More details

On your query, planner does something like

```
SELECT 0 AS position, loc FROM roads WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(-0.5,-0.5,0.5,0.5, 4326), loc)
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 AS position, loc FROM roads WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_MakeEnvelope(0.5,0.5,1.5,1.5, 4326), loc);

 Append  (cost=6.07..167.19 rows=170 width=36)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on roads  (cost=6.07..82.75 rows=85 width=36)
         Recheck Cond: ('...'::geometry && loc)
         Filter: _st_intersects('...'::geometry, loc)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on roads_loc_index  (cost=0.00..6.05 rows=254 width=0)
               Index Cond: ('...'::geometry && loc)
   ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on roads roads_1  (cost=6.07..82.75 rows=85 width=36)
         Recheck Cond: ('...'::geometry && loc)
         Filter: _st_intersects('...'::geometry, loc)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on roads_loc_index  (cost=0.00..6.05 rows=254 width=0)
               Index Cond: ('...'::geometry && loc)
(11 rows)
```

Notice the `->  Bitmap Heap Scan on roads`s. What I am emphasing is not the Bitmap heap Scan but the fact that there are as many `->` as there are positions. So idea is to let the planner "iterate" the roads as he wishes instead of telling him to `UNION ALL`.

Now note that by using (for 4000 positions)

```
WITH cte (pos, geom) AS ( SELECT 0, ST_MakeEnvelope(5687.5,5687.5,5688.5,5688.5, 4326)
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 1, ST_MakeEnvelope(13717.5,13717.5,13718.5,13718.5, 4326)
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 2, ST_MakeEnvelope(53009.5,53009.5,53010.5,53010.5, 4326)
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, ST_MakeEnvelope(60566.5,60566.5,60567.5,60567.5, 4326)
 UNION ALL 
SELECT 4, ST_MakeEnvelope(17843.5,17843.5,17844.5,17844.5, 4326) ) SELECT pos FROM cte;
```

which does "factor" the query as well, response time is 538ms. We don't even intersect roads, just **creating cte is slow**.

Conclusion when filling a `CTE` with custom values, avoid `UNION ALL` and just declare all the rows with `VALUES`.